# How to display HTML received in JSON using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

JSON

```
var obj = {
   content: "<p class="p1">Sample p tag one.</p> <p class="p1">Also 
   another paragraph sample.</p> <p><b>sample text</b></p> <p>More info <a 
   title="" href="https://www.google.com/" 
   target="_blank" rel="noopener"><em>THE WORK AHEAD: MACHINES, SKILLS AND 
   U.S. LEADERSHIP</em></a></p>"
};
```

How would I render this code in react? It shows all of the html tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through [`dangerouslySetInnetHTML`](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).

```
const htmlString = '<p>My html</p>';

const innerHtmlObject = {
  __html: htmlString,
};

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={innerHtmlObject} />
```

> **Note:** This is a bad practice that can lead to security vulnerability!

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the HTML.

You can do this through `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but it's safer to sanitize it first using something like `html-react-parser`.

```
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
```

Inside you render function:

```
<div>{Parser(obj.content)}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: this.state.obj.content
  }}
/>
```